# Looking for a faster function to add notes on specific cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, here is the link from my Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vROojeTBYnSQy0IeYY0vkzump-CPoDd5fyFuLwRZsjQ/edit?usp=sharing

I have 2 sheets: one (Sheet1) which contains a list of machines with an IP address, a Hostname and a switch + port. The objective of my script is to read the switch and the port of sheet 1, then put a note in the corresponding cell in sheet 2 (sheet 2 contains the diagram of the switches available with their 48 ports), the note must contain hostname and IP address.

The script works but adds the notes one by one, and it might take more than 30 minutes if my number of machines increases.

Do you have an idea to speed up the process?

Comment: You can process all the data and prepare an array of notes, and then use the [setNotes(notes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=uk#setNotes(Object)) method once instead of activating a cell in each iteration of the loop and writing a comment to it. I think that would be much faster

Comment: It is a good idea, i tried to do it but i don't know how to set the ranges where i want to set a note, because it can be everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You're currently iterating through the source values in `Sheet1` and using [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) to find the corresponding cells in `Sheet2`. Using `TextFinder` iteratively greatly increases the amount of requests to the spreadsheet, and that slows down the script a lot (see [Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services)).

Along the same lines, you are setting the notes for each cell individually via [setNote](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote), instead of setting all of them at once with [setNotes(notes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNotes(Object)), as [Sergey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189536/looking-for-a-faster-function-to-add-notes-on-specific-cells#comment122290823_69189536).

#### Solution:

I'd like to propose an alternative approach to minimize calls to the spreadsheet and so make the script considerably faster:

- Retrieve the useful data from `Sheet1` (`note`, `switch` and `port`), converting it to an array of objects for easier later retrieval.
- Retrieve all the data in `Sheet2` using [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate through the data in `Sheet2`, and for each row, check if either column A of the current row (for odd `port` numbers) or from two rows above (for even `port` numbers) contain a valid `switch` name (you can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that).
- If no valid `switch` name is found, return an array of `null` for this `map` iteration (since providing `null` as a parameter to `setNote` removes the note).
- If a valid `switch` name is found, iterate through that row's ports using `map`, and for each `port`, look for the valid combination of `switch` and `port` in the source data.
- If a valid combination of `switch` and `port` is found, return the corresponding `note` for that `map` iteration.
- If a valid combination is not found (that is, `Sheet1` doesn't contain data for that combination), return `null` for that iteration.
- Once you have build the 2D array of `notes` using the corresponding nested `maps`, set those notes to the `port` columns from `Sheet2`, using `setNotes`.

#### Code sample:

```
function actualiserNP2(){
  const SWITCH_COL = 1;
  const PORT_FIRST_COL = 4;
  const PORT_LAST_COL = 27; 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  const Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tabGeneral = Sheet1.getRange(10,2, Sheet1.getLastRow(), Sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const sourceData = tabGeneral.filter(row => row[7].includes("#")).map(row => {
    const [sw1a, sw1b] = row[7].split("#");
    const data = {
      "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
      "switch": sw1a,
      "port": sw1b
    }
    return data;
  });
  const targetData = Sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const notes = targetData.map((row,i) => {
    const sourceSwitch = sourceData.find(sourceRow => sourceRow["switch"] === row[SWITCH_COL-1] || (i > 1 && sourceRow["switch"] === targetData[i-2][SWITCH_COL-1]));
    if (sourceSwitch) {
      const currentSwitch = sourceSwitch["switch"];
      const ports = row.slice(PORT_FIRST_COL-1, PORT_LAST_COL);
      const rowNotes = ports.map(port => {
        const sourceRow = sourceData.find(row => row["switch"] === currentSwitch && Number(row["port"]) === Number(port));
        if (sourceRow) return sourceRow["note"];
        else return null;
      });
      return rowNotes;
    } else {
      return new Array(PORT_LAST_COL-PORT_FIRST_COL+1).fill(null);
    }
  });
  Sheet2.getRange(1, PORT_FIRST_COL, Sheet2.getLastRow(), PORT_LAST_COL-PORT_FIRST_COL+1).setNotes(notes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I im studying it, I will give you a feed back

Comment: It perfectly works, i have so much to learn. Thank you

Comment: lamblichus, could you explain to me why is there 2 parameters for the map : const notes = targetData.map((row,i) => {

Comment: @ThibaudGARNIER, an iteration index (second parameter) is needed to account for checking whether current row is two rows below the switch row (since that would be the row with even port numbers).

Comment: Ok thank you.
I am modifying your program because in my real file, each Host can have 3 ports, each of these ports can have its own IP address or not. It's very difficult because I'm still a beginner (I'm in a programming internship)

Comment: Is it possible to return many thing in the same condition of mapping ?

Comment: @ThibaudGARNIER I'd suggest you to post a new answer if you need further help.

Comment: @lamblichus i did it, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I modified lamblichus's script to adapt it to the 3 ports.
It works with this new script :

```
function actualiserNP1()
{
  const SWITCH_COL = 1;
  const PORT_FIRST_COL = 4;
  const PORT_LAST_COL = 27; 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
  const Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const tabGeneral = Sheet1.getRange(10,2, Sheet1.getLastRow(), Sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const data = [];
  const sourceData = tabGeneral.filter(row => row[7].includes("#") || row[11].includes("#") || row[15].includes("#")).map(row => { // On filtre les lignes ayant au moins un port
    
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 001
    
    if(row[7]=='' && row[11]=='' && row[15]!='')
    {
      if(row[13]!=''){
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[13]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
      }else{
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
      }
    }
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 010

    if(row[7]=='' && row[11]!='' && row[15]=='')
    {
      if(row[9]!=''){
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[9]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
        
      }
    }
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 011

    if(row[7]=='' && row[11]!='' && row[15]!='')
    {
      if(row[9]!=''){
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[9]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
      }
      // $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
      if(row[13]!=''){
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[13]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }
    }
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 100

    if(row[7]!='' && row[11]=='' && row[15]=='')
    {
      const [sw1a, sw1b] = row[7].split("#");
      data.push({
        "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
        "switch": sw1a,
        "port": sw1b
      })
      
    }
  //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 101

  if(row[7]!='' && row[11]=='' && row[15]!='')
    {
      if(row[13]!=''){
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[13]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

      const [sw1a, sw1b] = row[7].split("#");
    
      data.push({
        "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
        "switch": sw1a,
        "port": sw1b
      })
      
    }
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 110

    if(row[7]!='' && row[11]!='' && row[15]=='')
    {
      if(row[9]!=''){
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[9]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
      }else{
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
       
      }
      
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

      
        const [sw1a, sw1b] = row[7].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw1a,
          "port": sw1b
        })
        
    }
    //§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ 111

    if(row[7]!='' && row[11]!='' && row[15]!='')
    {
      if(row[9]!=''){
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[9]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw2a, sw2b] = row[11].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw2a,
          "port": sw2b
        })
        
      }
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

      if(row[13]!=''){
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[13]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }else{
        const [sw3a, sw3b] = row[15].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw3a,
          "port": sw3b
        })
        
      }
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

      
        const [sw1a, sw1b] = row[7].split("#");
      
        data.push({
          "note": `${row[0]}\n\n${row[5]}`,
          "switch": sw1a,
          "port": sw1b
        })
        
    }

    return data;
        
  });
  console.log(data)
  //console.log(sourceData);

  const targetData = Sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const notes = targetData.map((row,i) => {
    const sourceSwitch = data.find(sourceRow => sourceRow["switch"] === row[SWITCH_COL-1] || (i > 1 && sourceRow["switch"] === targetData[i-2][SWITCH_COL-1]));
    if (sourceSwitch) 
    {
      const currentSwitch = sourceSwitch["switch"];
      const ports = row.slice(PORT_FIRST_COL-1, PORT_LAST_COL);
      const rowNotes = ports.map(port => {
      const sourceRow = data.find(row => row["switch"] === currentSwitch && Number(row["port"]) === Number(port));
      if (sourceRow) return sourceRow["note"];
      else return null;
      });
      return rowNotes;
    } else {
      return new Array(PORT_LAST_COL-PORT_FIRST_COL+1).fill(null);
    }
  });

  Sheet2.getRange(1, PORT_FIRST_COL, Sheet2.getLastRow(), PORT_LAST_COL-PORT_FIRST_COL+1).setNotes(notes);
}
```

I am a begginer so i did instructions for each possible case.